# Obtainable chests?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I read somewhere that there were chests that you could pick up and add to your inventory, I read that you can access them by clutching through certain shops walls so I was wondering where I could find these chests, I have already tried looking them up but can't find anything, I am playing on ps4 if that helps

Comment: Could you provide the source where you read this? Because it doesn't make much sense to pick up chests. Perhaps you were referring to the Mad Masker mod? That has armor pieces which uses the textures of boss chests (and also increases carry weight by a lot).

Comment: Maybe it meant chestplates?

Answer (score 2):

Left of the iron mine in Dawn Star there is a chest badly hidden beneath the rocks. I believe it is the shopping chests of the khajiit Caravan. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBLPfQJb9-M) for the instructions on how to obtain it. AFAIK there is no such thing as picking up the chest or adding it to your inventory. The game mechanics wouldn't allow that.

The Dawn Star chest was patched with the unofficial patch, but that is a mod, so you can disable it your self if you have it.

Most shopping chests are pretty well hidden deep behind walls/rocks/earth. It would be quite difficult to reach them on the PS4.
On the PC one could simply open the console and type `tcl` to toggle the collision off.

Comment: I already know of those chests, I read in a dragon priest build that there were grabable chests, I want those

Comment: I assume 'grabbable' means 'in reach' where you're usually not supposed too. The chests in skyrim are furniture, which are by definition not grabbable. Unless you some kind of mod would make that possible (which I doubt would be easily possible).

Comment: Even after you grabbed it, what do you expect to happen?  It has no interface to place furniture like Fallout 4, so it'll just be stuck in your inventory.

Comment: "The game mechanics would allow that." - would or wouldn't?

Comment: @phflack thanks for pointing out the typo :). of course it is wouldn't.

Comment: If you look at how Heartfire works, you'll know right away that having furniture in your inventory is useless.  The game doesn't have any means of you placing down world objects from your inventory.  If you position yourself  correctly, you can literally see the house spawn out of thin air.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've misunderstood what you read, and that Mixiphoid's answer is correct.

---

If you *are* looking for more "portable storage", here is a list of options:

- When you level up, adding 10 points to your Stamina will also add 5 points to your carrying capacity.
- The pickpocketing perk *Extra Pockets* will add 100 to your carrying capacity.
- [*Fortify Carry Weight*](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fortify_Carry_Weight) enchantments are available for ring, neck, arm, and feet slots.  In addition, Thieves' Guild related body armor also carry the enchantment, as does the mask [Volsung](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Volsung_(item)).
- The [Aetherial Crown](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Aetherial_Crown) can hold the Steed Stone power for 100 carrying capacity, if Volsung's 20 isn't enough.
- Followers' own carrying capacity can be used as a convenient form of "Portable Storage".
- A [Dremora Butler](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Dremora_Butler) is worth another 148 carrying capacity worth of portable storage.
- Your carrying capacity is effectively unlimited when mounted.  I find [Arvak](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Arvak) to be the most *convenient* mount in the game.

Though if you truly want game breaking carrying capacity, I've seen mods that allow you to have groups of followers at the same time.

Comment: [Dead Bodies](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Chest#Portable_Containers) can be used as portable storage too :)

Comment: Actually, what you need is one of those "Friend" letters telling you about a shout.  Sticking that in a body turns it permanent, so you can stash infinite amount of stuff in it.  This isn't something I needed to do, but I think you can stuff items inside a chicken and pick it up and run at full speed.

Answer (score 0):

There are chests that you can pick up, but you can't store anything in them. They are labeled as "Do not delete", and you can sell them to fences for 200 gold. Look up merchant chest for the Hags Cure, in Markarth, on Youtube.